# Is there any research on specific details of ancient/medieval blacksmithing related to microelements added via plants?

Tags: technology, metallurgy

I have seen the following claim a couple of times before (all in Russian popular science type sources). However, I was never able to find historical OR scientific/technology research directly backing the claims up.

**The claim was that old time blacksmiths used specific *flowers/plants* in their work process that were, at the time, considered magic/ritual; but later on have proven to provide material benefit by introducing doping elements like tungsten/molybdenum into their iron.**

I wasn't able to find any references, though tungsten specifically is highly unlikely to have been the case as it is not known to be contained in any biologicals except some rare bacteria. Molybdenum seems to have been doped in by Japanese sword-makers by means of Molybdenum-rich sand, based on some info on the Wiki.

Is there any research supporting or refuting such claims?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about magic/ritual uses, and I'm not sure anyone could answer the 'why' someone tried something (until, at least, the scientific method) but there is evidence for seemingly random - but evidently useful - ingredients in metal work.

For example, *cupellation*, a technique for refining silver used in Roman period through to the 17th Century CE included a hearth lined with **bone ash**, a porous material that would absorb the molten oxidised metals (eg. copper).

Sadly, it looks like rare materials such as molybdenum were not widely used (including Japan) until an industrial process for formation/extraction was developed in the 18th century. However, in the process of creating a *carbon steel*, ingredients such as graphite were used which could contain the material.

Until then, it was probably dumb luck to find that a material had a hardening (or other characteristic) quality - if these pioneering blacksmiths even knew what they were doing. Certainly the spirit of experimentation with processes and alloys had led from copper through tin, bronze, iron and steel.

In terms of the 17th century CE Japanese example, perhaps it would be better to look at the reasons for this possible experimentation, namely the poor iron deposits on the Japanese islands and the need to work this into harder metals.

---

American Iron and Steel Institute (1948) *Steel Facts, Volumes 88-141*

Söderberg, A (2011) *Eyvind Skáldaspillir’s silver – refining and standards in pre-monetary economies in the light of finds from Sigtuna and Gotland*

Comment: Oh, I definitely don't imply that it was NOT dumb luck if they discovered that some technique worked (without realizing that the reason for it working was doping). Question is, DID they or did they not have known techniques that (a) are known to have been used consistently and (b) can be explain as "this worked because it doped the metal with this microelement".

Answer (score 3):

Plants have indeed been used to make steel suitable for swords.

Perhaps the most famous ancient swords were the so-called Damascus swords, made of wootz steel. They were called Damascus swords because the steel had a surface pattern that looked like damask. Wootz steel originated in south India around 300 BC, and around 2000 years ago was thought to be the finest steel in the world.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wootz_steel

To produce this, a small amount of iron, bamboo charcoal and the leaves of certain plants was put into a hermetically sealed clay crucible, and heated for a long time at temperatures of up to 1200ºC. The crucible had to be small to achieve those temperatures.

The iron was partly carburised (infused with carbon) by the charcoal, which lowered the melting point of the resultant alloy enough to achieve partial melting, which helped spread the carburisation. The result was a small cake of steel at the bottom of the crucible, with a carbon content of around 1.5%. It also included some other trace elements, such as vanadium and titanium, possibly from the bamboo or the other plants. This enhanced the hardness of the steel. The speculation is that the plants were originally included to ‘purify’ the steel, perhaps in a sort of religious rite, but adding them provided the trace elements needed to harden the steel.

This ‘crucible’ technique spread through central and east Asia, but not to Europe. The steel was only ever produced in small amounts, but its production in India lasted until the 19th century, at which point it was replaced by European steel.

Some references for this:

Alan Williams: The Sword and the Crucible

Madeleine Durand-Charre: Damascus and Pattern-Welded Steels